# How to deal with automated duplicate user removal

Tags: csv, powershell, error-handling, automation

I have the following:

```
@(Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dbs\Monday.csv) +
    @(Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dbs\Tuesday.csv) +
    @(Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dbs\Wednesday.csv) +
    @(Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dbs\Thursday.csv) +
    @(Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dbs\Friday.csv) |
  sort first_name,last_name,phone1 -Unique | 
  Export-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dbs\joined.csv

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#EDIT PATH SO IT POINTS TO DB FILE \/  
$newUserList = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dbs\joined.csv

ForEach ($item in $newUserList){ 
  $fname = $($item.first_name)
  $lname = $($item.last_name)
  $phone = $($item.phone1)

  $username=$fname+$lname.substring(0,1)

  # Puts Domain name into a Placeholder.
  $domain='@csilab.local'

  # Build the User Principal Name Username with Domain added to it
  $UPN=$username+$domain

  # Create the Displayname
  $Name=$fname+" "+$lname

  $newusers1 = (New-ADUser -GivenName $fname -Surname $lname -HomePhone $phone -Name $Name -DisplayName  $Name  -SamAccountName $username -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "1NewPassword" -asplaintext -force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Path "ou=test,dc=csi,dc=lab" -Enabled $true -PassThru) | 

  # I need this block to check for duplicates missed by the csv sort & merge
  # as well as any in the destination OU itself as the script will run daily
  # with inevitable possibility that user is unique to the csv but not the AD.
  $newusers1 | Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Active Users,DC=csilab,DC=local" |
    Sort-Object -Unique |
    Remove-ADUser -confirm:$false
```

However I run it and get:

```
Get-ADUser : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Team2.ps1:40 char:14
+ $newusers1 | Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Active Users,DC=csilab,DC=loca ...
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CN=Bethanie Cut...csilab,dc=local:PSObject) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

I also worry even if it did work that it'd delete the unique users instead of duplicates.

```
get-AdUser $username |  Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'OU=Active Users,dc=csilab,dc=local'  
}
```

What can I do to ensure all users are there without any originals getting deleted, just the duplicates?

Comment: Where does it clearly state that it created a user? It clearly states that there was an error trying to create the user because the user already exists, so no it didn't make a user. As such, `$newusers1` is null, and piping it to other commands is futile. For the second part, change it to `Get-ADUser $username` and I bet that you have a lot more luck with that part.

Comment: The original error message is rather self-explanatory. You already have an object `CN=Miss Dunning,dc=csi,dc=lab` in your AD. Double-check that. Also, `New-ADUser` doesn't return the user object if you don't use the parameter `-Passthru`, so `$newusers1` will always be empty. For further help you need to show your current code, the complete error message, and sample input data. Do not post that information in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers sorry, total noob. Edited it this time. :)

Comment: Your first code snippet is utterly broken and can't possibly work. And I still don't see a coherent error message or sample input. If you expect anyone to troubleshoot your problem: stop showing bits and pieces.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers tried to fix it and formatting, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have an empty pipe at the end of your `New-ADUser` statement, which would cause your script to fail with an "empty pipe element is not allowed" error, but oh well ...

To avoid collisions just check if an account already exists *before* you try to create it, and create it only if it doesn't:

```
$username = $fname + $lname.substring(0,1)
...
if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'") {
  Write-Host "Account $username already exists."
} else {
  New-ADUser -SamAccountName $username -Name $Name ... -PassThru
}
```

Also, you're overcomplicating the CSV handling. Simply process a list of the files via `ForEach-Object`:

```
$domain = '@csilab.local'

Set-Location 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dbs'

'Monday.csv', 'Tuesday.csv', 'Wednesday.csv', 'Thursday.csv', 'Friday.csv' |
  ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_ } |
  Sort-Object first_name, last_name, phone1 -Unique |
  ForEach-Object {
    $fname = $_.first_name
    $lname = $_.last_name
    $phone = $_.phone1
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ansgar, you've been a major help, this worked perfect! Thanks to all other contributors throughout this process as well. :D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Try/Catch:

```
Try {$newusers1=(New-ADUser–GivenName$fname–Surname$lname-HomePhone$phone–Name$Name-DisplayName  $Name  –SamAccountName$username–AccountPassword(ConvertTo-SecureString"1NewPassword"-asplaintext-force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon$true–UserPrincipalName$UPN–Path"dc=csi,dc=lab"-Enabled$true)}
Catch {
    If ($_.Exception.Message -match "account already exists")
    {
        #do whatever here, eg $NewUsers1 = Get-ADUser $Name
    }
}
```

Also, if you can't see the user when browsing via ADUC it could be that you are connected to a different DC.

As mentioned above, the newuser1 variable will be null if the command failed.  It will not load with the other user automatically, and it would be scary bad if it did.  You need to decide what to do if the account already exist, that may simply be loading the variable with the other account, or doing something like appending a "1" to $name and retrying the command.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using try/catch previously and for whatever reason PS ignores my Try block entirely. However it can't hurt to try again. What else could I do if that fails again?

Comment: Oh also, definitely not connected to different DC as there's only 1, the local one.

Comment: Ah, try putting an "-ErrorAction:Stop" at the end of the command to ensure the Catch gets triggered.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. The issue itself is resolved, script is fully functional, but I'm keeping these notes for reference. :) If threads should be removed let me know, or feel free to do so at admin digression... not sure how it works here